# How to "flick" a UIImageView?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, core-animation, quartz-graphics

I've got some UIViews that I'd like the user to be able to "flick" across the screen. They're not scroll views. They simply contain a raster image (png).  Can anyone point me to some sample code, etc to help get me started? Something a little more heavyweight than "MoveMe" out there that helps detect a "flick" (vs a "nudge" or a drag and drop) and then carries the view off in the direction of the "flick"?

*OpenGL probably overkill. If possible I'd like to stay w/in the realm of Core Graphics/Animation.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To detect the touch, in a view controller, you could use the touchesBegan and touchesEnded methods, store the touch from touchesBegan, and if the touch moved more than some amount to the left or right, it was a flick, not a nudge to the left or right.

Comment: yes, but that wouldn't distinguish a drag necessarily from a flick. perhaps I should have been more specific. someone "picking something up" and "dropping" it needs to be handled differently from someone "flicking" (throwing) it.

Comment: What is the difference between a "pick something up" and "drop" it and flicking something?

Comment: imagine a coin on your desk. you could pick it up and drop it in a bowl or you could "flick" it to another part of your desk. you accelerate it with the flick and then "gravity" & "friction" bring it to rest...

Answer (score 2):

I would say that the easyeist way to implement this would be to put your views in an UIScrollView container with paging enabled and let it worry about all the "flicking" actions. Works great for me.

You can even with some additional effort have views lazy load the images.

Comment: But I don't want any scroll effect. I want the objects to to stay w/in the bounds of the screen. I just want a quick flick gesture to send them from one side of the screen to the other. so the flick would set them in motion and then "gravity" & "friction" would slow them down...

Comment: This was the perfect solution in my case, as I only needed left or right movement for a swipe to dismiss effect.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you could achieve this easily by taking the nazgul42 answer and checking also the time  between the two mentioned events. Short time and long distance combined could be then interpreted as flick. Also you can determine the direction of the flick by calculating the coordinates both touch event points.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have an `UIView` called `aView` and two `UIImageViews`, `page1` and `page2`. Supposing you have `page1` already as a subview in `aView`, this code will flip from `page1` to `page2`:

```
[UIView beginAnimations:@"someId" context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromLeft forView:aView cahe:YES];
[page1 removeFromSuperview];
[aView addSubview:page2];
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

Comment: I'm not transitioning between "pages" per say. More like trying to toss images from one side of screen to the other.

Answer (score 0):

I found a thread here, although the method worries me -

http://discussions.apple.com/message.jspa?messageID=7862186

It doesn't take speed or timestamps into account; just the distance since the last event update. If Apple ever changed the freqency/granularity of event updates, this code could break.

Answer (score 0):

try using `UIPanGentureRecognizer` Sample code :

```
UIPanGestureRecognizer *imageGesture = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc]
                                         initWithTarget:self
                                         action:@selector(imageDragged:)];
[imageView1 addGestureRecognizer:imageGesture];
```

then

```
- (void)imageDragged:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)gesture{
UIImageView *imageView = (UIImageView *)gesture.view;
CGPoint translation = [gesture translationInView:imageView];

imageView.center = CGPointMake(imageView.center.x + translation.x,
                               imageView.center.y + translation.y);
imageView2.center = imageView.center;
imageView3.center = imageView.center;

[gesture setTranslation:CGPointZero inView:imageView];}
```